# Help with Antiderivative (couple of questions)

Tags: integration

I am not very good at this and still trying to understand how it works, but I really need to find a antiderivative of $ x^6$. Would be very glad if someone could help me with that.

Comment: The rule is $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{n+1} x^{n+1})=x^n$. Here $n=6$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The antiderivative of $\int$$x^6$$dx$ simply using reverse power rule

$\frac{x^7}{7}+C$

The rule is $\int$$x^n$$dx$$=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$+C$.

Comment: In spite of the downvote the answer completely address the question.

Comment: And the answer is completely correct. The downvote is simply spiteful for having answered the question, which some deem inappropriate for their own puritanical purposes.

Comment: @amWhy I've been the target of this sort of petty downvote before, which is why my answer (made earliest) was just a heavy hint, leaving the asker to do some of the work. Alas, that didn't save me a downvote from an especially swollen-headed puritan. :)

Answer (score 3):

$$\int x^6 dx = \frac{x^7}{7}+C$$
because
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{x^7}{7}+C\right]=\frac{7x^6}{7}+0=x^6$$

More generally, for all $n \ne -1$,
$$\int x^n dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$
because
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C\right]=\frac{(n+1)x^n}{n+1}+0=x^n$$

Answer (score 1):

The antiderivative of $x^n$ is $\frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1} + c$, where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

Now apply this to your problem.

Comment: Your answer is spot on! A very appropriate "lead" that requires the the OP to apply it. Maintain courage in the face of the "swollen-headed" puritans that abound here!

Comment: @amWhy Thanks! :)